# Image segmentation based on binary image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation, edge-detection

I have these two images, **image 1** is a binary of **image 2**.

I would like to segment out the object from **image 2** in the shape of **image 1**.

```
           image 1                            image 2
```

[image]
[image]

I have looked into several samples but none of them is helpful. Thought of overlaying image 2 onto image 1's white area, using copyTo function with the conditions, but I'm sure there's a better way. Would really appreciate if someone can tell me the method or C++ snippet code to solve this!

Comment: Where's the code ??  What did you try ??

Comment: You can try image masking...

Comment: @Christophe I thought of overlaying image 2 onto image 1's white area, using copyTo function with the conditions. But I am sure there's a better way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

As stated you can perform image **masking** instead of using **copying** in C++:

```
cv::bitwise_and(image1, image2, output);
```

where `image1` is the mask and `image2` is the original image.

Another method that works for me is this:

```
image2.copyTo(image1, image1);
```

where `image1` is the mask and `image2` is the original image. The result is shown below:

[image]

Comment: `setTo` with a mask is much clearer. in my opinion.

Comment: @Miki Cool. Are there any performance issues among the two? Or do both the functions take same computation time?

Comment: Probably the same.... I think that "I'm setting to this value according to this mask" is less confusing than "I'm and-ing this two images"

Comment: @JeruLuke. Thanks, It has an error "Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is neither 'array op array')". But I'm sure I can solve it with your method. Could you tell me the reason I get the down votes (beginner here)? I have did the research on the image segmentation for almost a day..

Comment: Misinterpretation of your question led to the downvotes I guess. Image **segmentation** and image **masking** are separate operations altogether. You should mentioned (or searched) for image masking.

Comment: @Samuel because 1) this question is asked every other day, 2) there's no evidence you actually tried something. You can show the code you tried in the question.

Comment: Trivial mistakes happen with beginners, I was once in your stage too :D

Comment: @Miki I actually tried the same method and faced the same error (until now). The error couldn't be solved with changing the masking channel. Was thinking I was off course, that's why I asked for method. But thanks to your explanation, I shall show some evidence next time I ask questions! :)

Comment: @JeruLuke Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: @Samuel I see you have worked out your problem. Great job. keep learning!!!

Answer (score -2):

You need to Otsu threshold to separate the foreground from the background

```
/**@file
  Get the Otusu threshold for image segmentation.
  @param[in] gray - the grayscale image
  @param width - image width
  @param height - image height
  @returns Threshold at which to split pixels into foreground and
           background.
  @image html maggie.jpg  Margaret Thatcher (1925-2013) greyscale photograph
  @image html maggieotsu.gif Mrs Thatcher Otsu thresholded
 */
int getOtsuthreshold(unsigned char *grey, int width, int height)
{
  int hist[256] = {0};
  int wB = 0;
  int wF;
  float mB, mF;
  float sum = 0;
  float sumB = 0;
  float varBetween;
  float varMax = 0.0f;
  int answer = 0;
  int i;
  int k;

  for(i=0;i<width*height;i++)
    hist[grey[i]]++;

  /* sum of all (for means) */
  for (k=0 ; k<256 ; k++) 
       sum += k * hist[k];

  for(k=0;k<256;k++)
  {
     wB += hist[k];               
     if (wB == 0) 
         continue;

     wF = width*height - wB;            
     if (wF == 0) 
       break;

     sumB += (float) (k * hist[k]);

     mB = sumB / wB;            /* Mean Background */
     mF = (sum - sumB) / wF;    /* Mean Foreground */

     /* Calculate Between Class Variance */
     varBetween = (float)wB * (float)wF * (mB - mF) * (mB - mF);

     /* Check if new maximum found */
     if (varBetween > varMax) 
     {
       varMax = varBetween;
       answer = k;
     }

  }
  return answer;
}
```

https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/binaryimagelibrary

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to answer **this** question? Even so, you can use `cv::threshold(..., THRESH_OTSU)`... no need for an external library